# В чём ошибка с запросом в который пытаюсь передать переменную?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, jwt

Пишу на node.js и параллельно использую библиотеку pg, то есть без всяких орм пишу напрямую sql-код

```js
    class UserController {
    async registration(req, res, next) {
        const {id, email, password, role} = req.body

        if (!email || !password) {
            return next(ApiError.badRequest('Некорректный email или password'))
        }
        const candidate = await db.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE (email) = ($1)', [email])
        console.log(candidate)
        if (candidate) {
            return next(ApiError.badRequest('Пользователь с таким email уже существует'))
        }
        const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 5)
        const user = await db.query(`INSERT INTO users (id, email, password, role) values($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *`, [id, email, hashPassword, role] )

        const token = generateJwt(id, email, role)
        res.json(user)
        return res.json({token})
    }
}
```

пытался переменную вписать ${email} вот так и по всякому, но когда отправляю запрос, пишет, что "error: столбец "email" не существует".
В чём проблема?

Comment: Так может в вашей таблице нет такого поля? Или написано немного по другому? Можете вывести итоговый запрос, который уходит в БД? И что будет, если этот запрос выполнить напрямую руками в БД?

Comment: в таблице поле есть, название поля копировал прямо оттуда, я бы скриншот даже приложил. Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду. Открыть бд и туда этот запрос вписать?

Comment: Ну да, вывести текст запроса, который уходит в БД и этот же запрос выполнить руками в БД. Если получаете ошибку, что столбца нет, значит что с ним не так...

Comment: ага, всё таки ошибся, извиняюсь, кучу раз проверял, что так или не так. Но теперь проблема в другом.